# How do I keep my Dropdown open on highlight input, drag, release?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using the react bootstrap Dropdown component. I'm noticing specific behavior I don't like. Best to explain with pictures.

I have a dropdown with an input filter box and a list.

[image]

When the user types text into the input box, goes to highlight that text, drags mouse to the left, and releases the mouse outside of the dropdown, the dropdown closes.

This is annoying behavior for the user who like to be able to select the text to delete it, and re-enter new search text.

[image]

Now please don't think the behavior I want is to *not* close the dropdown when the user clicks outside. I still do. The difference is I don't want the dropdown to close when the user clicks inside the dropdown -> drags mouse to outside boundary -> releases.

I've researched this a lot already but I'm struggling with knowing what to look for. I just need to be pointed in the right direction. I'm new to using React, and not sure how to get into the weeds when custom behavior is required. I would prefer to do this with React, I do not want to use jQuery.

Anyway, I will appreciate any help someone can give me. Thank you!

Comment: Please include a minimal code snippet that demonstrates the problem. The built-in code tool allows reactjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the `<Dropdown.Menu/>` listens for `click` and `mousedown` events. So, when you select, drag and release the mouse it will be considered as a click. This will close the popup.

To fix this make the dropdown listen to only mousedown with `rootCloseEvent="mousedown"`

```
    <Dropdown.Menu rootCloseEvent="mousedown">
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1">Red</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2">Blue</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="3" active>Orange</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1">Red-Orange</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!! I did exactly what your example had in my own code, and it worked!